# How to build a Multiple Repositories in one project using Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, git, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I would like to ask,
what is the better structure and how to implement multiple repo in one project

I'm planning to create a structure like this one.

[image]

Is it possible?
Then it serve using a node server.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Comment: @InfoStatus - Yes, using nginx

Comment: Hi Mark, how did you get sorted? 3 different repos? dd you create libraries or modules to inject? I am in the same position right now

Comment: @EnriqueAparicio, I'm not sure if this the best solution, each child repository will ignore the other repositories. Then, if there are changes on each repo, it will automatically pull on each repo using jenkins. Then, rebuild.

Let me know if you find another solution.
Thank you